# Make a quoted text highlighted

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use RegExp to make a quoted text bold.

**For example**

```
var string = 'Hello "Joe"';
var regex = new RegExp(/"[a-zA-Z]"/g);
var el = document.getElementById('element');
el.innerHTML = string.replace(regex, ???); // Here '???' means I don't know what to write at second argument.
```

I'm new with `RegExp`, so don't bother with my above code.

Comment: And the quantifier `+` is missing: `var regex = /"([a-zA-Z]+)"/g;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<span>` with a class `highlight` to wrap the quoted text.

The RegEx `/"[a-zA-Z]"/g` will match only a single alphabet inside double-quotes. To match a single word inside double-quotes, use `+` quantifier on the alphabets character class. `/"[a-zA-Z]+"/g`. This can be shortened by using the case-insensitive flag `i`, `/"[a-z]+"/gi`.

To match any number of words inside double-quotes, use the RegEx `"([^"]+)"`. The match can then be accessed by using the first captured group `$1`.

```
var regex = /"([^"]+)"/g;
var el = document.getElementById('element');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

```js
var regex = /"([^"]+)"/g;
var el = document.getElementById('element');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

```css
span.highlight {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">Dennis Ritchie the creator of C used "Hello World!" to try out the language, and from then it has become the standard to use "Hello World".</div>
```

To match **single/double quotes**, you can use the RegEx `/(["'])(.*?)\1/g`.

1. `(["'])`: Match a single quote(`'`) or double-quote(`"`) exactly once, add the match to the first captured group. Can also be written as `("|')`
2. `(.*?)`: Match anything that is not newline **non-greedy**, add the match in the second captured group
3. `\1`: Back-reference. Use the match from the first captured group.

To use this RegEx to replace, use the second captured group `$2`.

```
.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$2</span>');
```

```js
var regex = /(['"])(.*?)\1/g;
var el = document.getElementById('element');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$2</span>');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 'elit', sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 'laboris' nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure "dolor" in reprehenderit in 'voluptate' velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

---

To set the styles of the highlighted text, the class `highlight` can be used.

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not mandatory of RegEx then:)

```
var str = 'Hello "Joe"';
str = str.split("\"").map(function (value, index) {
    if(index % 2 == 0) {
        return value
    } else {
        return "<span>" + value + "</span>"
    }
}).join("");
```

This outputs

```
"Hello <span>Joe</span>"
```

**Explanation of code:**

1. Split by double quote `"` and get an array. Items at odd index would be the one which were inside the quotes.
2. Iterate over array and replace the items at odd index with their value encapsulated by `<span> value </span>`
3. Join the array with empty string `""`

Comment: I like shorter syntax: `str.split("\"").map((value, index)  => index % 2 === 0 ? value : "<span>" + value + "</span>").join("")`